# O que é a constant pool em Java?

Tags: java, jvm

Estou lendo a Java Virtual Machine Specification para me aprofundar um pouco mais
e não entendi perfeitamente o que é a tabela constant pool. Por exemplo, ao falar 
da run-time constant pool a especificação cita esta tabela:

> A run-time constant pool is a per-class or per-interface run-time
>   representation of the constant_pool table in a class file (§4.4). It
>   contains several kinds of constants, ranging from numeric literals
>   known at compile-time to method and field references that must be
>   resolved at run-time. The run-time constant pool serves a function
>   similar to that of a symbol table for a conventional programming
>   language, although it contains a wider range of data than a typical
>   symbol table.

Tradução:

> A run-time constant pool é uma representação de tempo de execução por classe ou por interface da tabela constant_pool em um arquivo .class (§4.4). Ela contém vários tipos de constantes, que variam de literais numéricos conhecidos em tempo de compilação a referências de método e de campo que devem ser resolvidas em tempo de execução. A run-time constant pool serve uma função semelhante à de uma tabela de símbolos para uma linguagem de programação convencional, apesar de conter uma mais ampla gama de dados do que uma tabela de símbolos típica.

Que tipos de constantes existem nessa tabela e qual a sua utilitade? Gostaria de saber também qual a diferença entre constant pool e run-time constant pool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando o arquivo .java é compilado, é gerado um arquivo .class. Esse arquivo .class possui os Java Byte Codes que são o código java transformado em instruções de máquinas genéricas. Esses byte codes utilizam dados como nome de variáveis, valores literais, referências de classes, referências de métodos, etc. Para economizar a quantidade de bytes necessários para representar esses dados, os byte codes utilizam a constant pool. A constant pool possui todos esses dados e o byte code possui uma referência para ela.

Esse link fala sobre os byte codes:
http://www.nessauepa.com.br/blog/2013/08/bytecode-java/

Cada arquivo .class possui uma constant pool. Além disso, quando o .java é compilado, são criadas ligações com todas as classes que ele se relaciona através de referências simbólicas. Chama-se referência simbólica porque não representa o endereço real de memória. As referências simbólicas também estão na constant pool.

É possível ver o conteúdo gerado no .class utilizando o seguinte comando no cmd:

```
javap.exe -verbose NomeAbsolutoDoArquivo.class > NomeAbsolutoDeUmArquivoTxt.txt
```

Será escrito no arquivo NomeAbsolutoDeUmArquivoTxt.txt o conteúdo do .class em linguagem humana.
Nesse arquivo será possível ver a constant pool gerada.
Para executar esse comando é preciso estar dentro do diretório %JAVA_HOME%\bin.

Quando a JVM é instanciada e a classe é carregada, é criada também a run-time constant pool que é baseada na constant pool. Quando uma referência simbólica precisar ser utilizada, ela será traduzida no endereço real.

Esse link fala sobre constant pool x run-time constant pool e a referência simbólica:
http://javaguiadoscuriosos.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/primeiramente-ando-meio-sem-tempo-para.html

A JVM, como o próprio nome já diz, é uma máquina virtual. Essa máquina será responsável, dentre outras coisas, em fazer o gerenciamento de memória utilizada pelo programa java em execução. A JVM é instanciada quando o programa é iniciado.

Uma explicação sobre o funcionamento da JVM pode ser encontrada nesse artigo:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/entenda-como-funciona-a-java-virtual-machine-jvm/27624

A JVM possui algumas áreas de memória. Duas áreas bem conhecidas são a HEAP e a STACK. Todos os objetos ficam na HEAP. A STACK funciona da seguinte forma:
Toda vez que um método for invocado, será criado um frame contendo variáveis locais, valor de retorno, operand stack e a referência para a run-time constant pool da classe que possui o método. Esse frame será adicionado no topo da stack. Quando o método terminar de executar e retornar, o frame será removido da stack. A stack segue a estrutura de dados LIFO (Last In First Out).

Uma explicação muito boa sobre o gerenciamento de memória da JVM, pode ser encontrada aqui:
http://luizricardo.org/2014/11/entendendo-as-configuracoes-de-memoria-da-maquina-virtual-java-jvm/

Além da HEAP, existe uma área chamada de NON-HEAP. Nessa área está localizada a run-time constant pool. As classes que serão utilizadas pelo programa serão carregadas também nessa área. É na NON-HEAP que fica o PermGen explicado no artigo do Luiz Ricardo citado acima.

A imagem a seguir mostra as três áreas de memória comentadas, mostra que a run-time constant pool está na NON-HEAP e que ela é referenciada pelo frame que está na STACK:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse link fala em detalhes sobre a jvm:
http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html#constant_pool

Conclusão:

> Para que serve a constant pool?

Guardar informações que serão utilizadas pelos byte code.

> Que tipos de dados ficam na constant pool?

Valores literais, referências de classe, referências de método, referências de atributos, constantes.

> Qual a vantagem da constant pool?

Economizar a quantidade de bytes utilizados no byte code.

> Qual a diferença do constant pool e run-time constant pool?

A constant pool está no .class. A run-time constant pool está no NON-HEAP, passa a existir quando a classe é carregada na jvm. É baseada na constant pool.

Comment: Ok, a resposta ficou bem completa! Se tiver alguma sugestão para melhorar a pergunta também será bem vinda, podemos ir melhorando a página com o tempo. A resposta e os links ajudaram bastante, agora estou programando um pouco em bytecode pra entender essas partes internas do java mais na prática. Várias coisas do java estão começando a fazer muito mais sentido. Obrigado pela dedicação =) .

Comment: @SérgioMucciaccia de nada. Com certeza. Vamos melhorando com o tempo. Você pode dar uma olhada também no open JDK. Ver o código fonte para entender melhor. Quem sabe até contribuir. http://openjdk.java.net/. Eu vi que o James D Bloom, autor do artigo do último link, aprendeu muita coisa vendo o código.